# I need help fixing a logic error in my code that is supposed to find number of times certain letters occur in a .txt file java

Tags: java, logic

I have a program that finds the number of times that four letters occur in a .txt file, but it does not find the right number of letters.  What is causing this problem, and how do I fix it?  Why does my program only count some letters and ignores others?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Count {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws  FileNotFoundException {

        String phrase;    // a string of characters
        int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase
        int length;       // the length of the phrase
        char ch;          // an individual character in the string
        int countA;
        int countE;
        int countS;
        int countT;

        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("counting.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner (file);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        phrase = inFile.nextLine();
        length = phrase.length();

        // Initialize counts
        while (true) {
            if (phrase.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                break;
            } else {
                countBlank = 0;
                countA = 0;
                countE = 0;
                countS = 0;
                countT = 0;

                for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
                    if ( phrase.charAt( i ) == ' ' ) {
                        countBlank++;
                    }

                    ch = phrase.charAt(i);

                    switch (ch) {
                        case 'a':
                        case 'A':  countA++;
                        break;
                        case 'e':
                        case 'E':  countE++;
                        break;
                        case 's':
                        case 'S':  countS++;
                        break;
                        case 't':
                        case 'T':  countT++;
                        break;
                    }
                }


                System.out.println ();
                System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
                System.out.println ();

                System.out.println ("Number of A's: " + countA);
                System.out.println ();
                System.out.println ("Number of E's: " + countE);
                System.out.println ();
                System.out.println ("Number of S's: " + countS);
                System.out.println ();
                System.out.println ("Number of T's: " + countT);
                break;
            } /* else */

        } /* while loop */

    } /* end main */
} /* end Class Count */
```

Comment: What is your actual output? Are you getting a result less than the expected? Are you getting 0?

Comment: I am getting less than I expected.  I was supposed to get 3 a's 7 e's, 4 s, 3 t's, and    This is what I got                       Number of blank spaces: 6

Number of A's: 0

Number of E's: 4

Number of S's: 0

Number of T's: 2

Comment: Start by indenting the code properly. The error will be identified easily when it's done.

Comment: OK. Now that the code is indented: how many lines does the program actually read, i.e. how many times is `inFile.nextLine()`executed? Don't you find it strange that the code reading the line is not in the while loop? How many iteration does the while loop do? Don't you find it strange that, whatever the line contains, you always end up calling `break;`, which ends the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this snippet of code, to be inserted once the scanner is instantiated.

```
String everything = ""; //Makes a blank string
while(infile.hasNext())
everything += infile.next(); //Fills the string with everything from the text file
everything = everything.toLowerCase(); //converts the string to lowercase, so you don't have to compare multiple cases

for(char c : everything.toCharArray())//converts everything to an array of characters, runs a for each on it with c as a character
if(Character.isWhiteSpace(c)) //if the character is a space, increase the countBlank var
countBlank++;
else
switch (c) //switch you had to increase the count of a letter
        {
     case 'a':
         countA++;
         break;
     case 'e':
         countE++;
         break;
     case 's':
         countS++;
         break;
     case 't':
         countT++;
         break;
      }
```

Tell me if you need me to explain any of the code for you.

Comment: do i need to get rid of anything in my code when i replace my current code with this?

Comment: @user3188303: don't replace your code by the code of someone else without understanding why your code wasn't  right, and what the code you paste actually does. You won't learn anything by doing that. Read my comment, and try to think about what the code does. Execute the code step by step in your brain, or on a sheet of paper. It takes time to learn. Your code is almost correct. You just have to think about what I highlighted in my comment.

Comment: @user3188303 I actually had a bit of an error. I confused the Scanners `infile` and `scan`, which might have thrown you off. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `countMatches` method from `StringUtils`. 
Have a look at the documentation [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Your code could be re-written like -

```
String phrase = "";
while(inFile.hasNext()) {
   phrase += inFile.nextLine();
}
phrase = phrase.toLowerCase();

countBlank = StringUtils.countMatches(phrase, " ");
countA = StringUtils.countMatches(phrase, "a");
countE = StringUtils.countMatches(phrase, "e");
countS = StringUtils.countMatches(phrase, "s");
countT = StringUtils.countMatches(phrase, "t");
```